# Web Audio ScriptNode not called after button onclick

Tags: javascript, audio, web, onclick

(Windows 7/64, FireFox 41.0.1)  I have a web audio network that consists of a (live mic) source connected to a script node, connected to the destination.  If I include a button element with no "onclick" script, the script node (which just does a "console.log") keeps functioning.  If I include an onclick script, after executing the script the script node never gets called again, even though the onclick script just sends a message to the console.  If there's no onclick script, it works; if the button calls an onclick script, the script node is no longer called. Here is the FireBug console with no onclick script:

Edit:  If I click on the button when there's an onclick script, the messages from the scriptNode halt.  However, if I then put a breakpoint in the scriptNode, the breakpoint is hit, showing that the scriptNode is called.  If I then remove the breakpoint and tell FireBug to continue, the scriptnode continues to display its message until I hit the button again.

Here is the output with no onclick script called:
    144 scriptNode.onaudioprocess bug.html (line 35)
(the count continues to grow)

---

Here is the output with the onclick script called:

```
36 scriptNode.onaudioprocess bug.html (line 35)
hello bug.html (line 62)
```

(no further output)

---

Here's the entire code.  Can anyone tell me where I've gone wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <title>Bug</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jwm.css">

    </head>
    <body>

        <button onclick="sayHello()">Click me</button><br>
        <!-- <button>Click me</button><br> -->

        <script>
            // Encapsulate the client code in this single function.
            //
            function runClient(sock,beatsPerCycle,beatsPerMinute) {

                // Do necessary fallbacks to get the user media.
                navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia ||
                          navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                          navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                          navigator.msGetUserMedia);

                // Set up the context.
                var audioContext = new AudioContext();

                // Set up the script node that does all the work.
                var scriptNode = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(0, 2, 2);

                scriptNode.onaudioprocess = function(audioProcessingEvent) {
                    console.log("scriptNode.onaudioprocess");
                };

                if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
                    navigator.getUserMedia(
                        {
                            audio: true
                        },
                        function (stream) {
                            var source = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
                            // Next line courtesy of
                            // https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/984179
                            window.horrible_hack_for_mozilla = source;
                            source.connect(scriptNode);
                            scriptNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
                        },
                        function(err) {
                            console.log("The following getUserMedia error occured: " + err);
                            throw("");
                        }
                    );
                } else {
                    console.log("browser does not have getUserMedia.");
                }
            }

            function sayHello() {
                console.log("hello");
            }

            runClient()
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

With this version of Firefox, at least, calling the "onclick" script results in *something* changing the AudioContext state to "suspended," thus halting any further audio processing.  Setting a breakpoint, waiting for the break, then continuing execution, causes the AudioContext state to resume to "running" and audio processing resumes.  For my purposes, I now include this function

```
audioContext.onstatechange = function() {
    if (audioContext.state === "suspended") {
    audioContext.resume();
    }
}
```

This hack seems to have resolved my problem.  Hope it helps someone else, too.